# Не получается составить линейный односвязный список

Tags: c, список, односвязный-список

Программа компилируется, но при запуске появляется ошибка "Прекращена работа программы"

Только начала погружаться в эту тему и никак не могу понять, в чём ошибка :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct List
{
    node_t *head;
    int size;
} list_t;

void
init (list_t *l)
{
    l->head = NULL;
    l->size = 0;
}

void 
push_back (list_t *l, int value)
{
    node_t *cur = l->head;
    while (cur->next != NULL) cur = cur->next;
    node_t *tmp = (node_t*) malloc (sizeof (node_t));
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    cur->next = tmp;
    l->size++;
}

void
print_list (list_t *l)
{
    node_t *cur = l->head;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", cur->value);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void 
destroy (list_t *l)
{
    node_t *cur = l->head;
    node_t *tmp;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        tmp = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
        free (tmp);
    }
}

int 
main ()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    list_t *l = NULL;
    init (l);
    push_back (l, x);
    push_back (l, y);
    print_list (l);
    destroy (l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так написан бред: в функцию `init` передается null-указатель, а затем через этот null-указатель что-то пытаются писать. Ну все и падает. Что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: какое тогда начальное значение l должно быть?

Comment: `list_t *l = (list_t*) malloc (sizeof (list_t));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я малость изменил ваш код, сейчас он выглядит по-людски :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *initNode(int value)
{
    Node *res = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    res->value = value;
    res->next = NULL;
    return res;
}

typedef struct list
{
    Node* head;
    int size;
} List;

List *initList()
{
    List* _list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    _list->head = NULL;
    _list->size = 0;
    return _list;
}
// Использую рекурсию, чтобы удалять Nodes | можно написать свою версию с линейным удалением (оно в вашем коде, но так красивее и вероятность ошибки меньше)
void deleteNodes(Node* _node)
{
    if (_node!=NULL)
        deleteNodes(_node->next);
    else
        return;
    printf("\nI'm going to delete Node with value = %d, located in %d", _node->value, _node);
    free(_node);
}

void deleteList(List* _list)
{
    deleteNodes(_list->head);
    free(_list);
}

void pushToList(List* _list, int value)
{
    _list->size++;
    // Голова листа изначально указывает на NULL, а после первого пуша начинает уже на новый элемент
    if (_list->head == NULL)
    {
        _list->head = initNode(value);
        return;
    }

    Node* head = _list->head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        prev = head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    head = initNode(value);
    prev->next = head;
}

void printList(List* _list)
{
    Node *cur = _list->head;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", cur->value);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    List* _list = initList();
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
        pushToList(_list, i);
    printList(_list);
    deleteList(_list);
}
```